# calling wget from a browser using php

Tags: apache-httpd, php, wget

My httpd is running with a daemon user. I want to do a wget using php from FTP server. When I run the php from linux server, the same downloads the required file from FTP. But when I call the same php from browser, it does not download the file. On checking the logs of of apache2, I found the below error message.

```
wget: /opt/lampstack-5.6.31-0/common/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by wget)
wget: /opt/lampstack-5.6.31-0/common/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by wget)
wget: /opt/lampstack-5.6.31-0/common/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by wget)
```

Can I know how to run wget and download required file to overcome this error?

Comment: You have libcurl in php, no need to call wget

Comment: but will it allow me to download the file from ftp? I am calling the same via browser

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using chrome

Comment: I have wrriten a javascript which will call the php using post method. That php inturn calls wget. Wanted to know how I can download the required file from FTP using wget in php.

Comment: I even tried with curl, I am getting error with fopen itself. Permission denied.
`failed to open stream: Permission denied`

Comment: I would advise deleting this question, posting the code using libcurl and asking in StackOverflow.